# DAX Measure: case based on other column text values

Tags: powerbi, case, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure

I have a big model in PowerBI where there are many different aggregation and grouping based on columns being displayed or not on the final table.

Simplifying: I need to do a conditional statement doing the **sum if the value of column 1 is A1 but doing the MAX() if the value of column 1 is A2.**

[image]

I need to have that information in the same column of the final output.

How would you go for this one?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

if you have only two values you can do a simple IF like this :

```
Measure = IF ( SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[Column1]) = "A1", SUM('Table'[Column2]), MAX('Table'[Column2]))
```

[image: FinalProduct]

Comment: Assume that OP didn't use a slicer. How do you ensure that only one value is selected in your measure if there is no row context?

Comment: Because that's how Power BI works, if you use a table as your visual, and you put column1 as one column it will take only the distinct values and select that value for the measure calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

```
TblMeasure =
VAR TblSummary =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        VALUES ( FactTable[Column1] ),
        "Test",
            IF (
                FactTable[Column1] = "A1",
                SUM ( FactTable[Column2] ),
                MAX ( FactTable[Column2] )
            )
    )
RETURN
    SUMX ( TblSummary, [Test] )
```

If we test it on a table visual:

[image: TblVisual]